# generating a random number between 1 and 20

Tags: vba

The code I previously used was

```
Randomvariable = 1 + Int((20 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())
```

I'm a bit concerned it wasn't right because the format I'm seeing online in guides is

```
random_number = Int(20 * Rnd) + 1
```

Was my way equivalent to this?

Comment: `20 - 1 + 1 = 20` and `1 + Int() = Int() + 1`

Comment: ah ok so it's the same cheers. Seems obvious now lol I just know nothing about vba

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a read about the [**Rnd()**](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php) function

The general formula is

```
Int ((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
```

Therefore if you want to generate random numbers between 1 and 20 use

```
Int((20 - 1 + 1 ) * Rnd + 1)
```

Comment: oh i see what you mean now, see simoco's comment it pretty much answers your question about +1