# Randomly Assign Employees to Tasks

Tags: vba, excel, loops

This is a follow-up to a previous question that I had. I was provided an answer, but due to my own inexperience and inability, I can't seem to implement it properly.

My situation is as follows:
I need to assign a list of employees to tasks.

- There will always be MORE tasks than employees.
- Each employee must be assigned to at least ONE
- No employee should be assigned to more than two
- I need the employee list to randomize during the sorting process so the same employees don't get the same tasks over and over

Where I am coming up short is finding a way that starts "assigning" employees, keeps track of how many times the array(i) employee has been assigned, and if it's greater than two, move onto the next.

An awesome user tried helping me here: [Excel VBA to assign employees to tasks using loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364276/excel-vba-to-assign-employees-to-tasks-using-loops?noredirect=1#comment83715653_48364276)

Here is the "test" table I am working with:

[image: Picture of the test table]

Here is the macro I have written to sort my list of employees, which works:

```
Sub ShuffleEmp()
' This macro's intention is to shuffle the current liste of process assessors

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim tempString As String, tempInteger As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, lastRow As Integer

    ' this grabs the last row with data, so that it can be dynamic
    With Sheets("Test")
        lastRow = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    ' this assumes ALWAYS 45 tasks
    ' starting row 6, going until row 35
    For i = 6 To lastRow
        ' row 6, column 14 (next to Emp column) to start....
        Cells(i, 14).Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 1000)
    Next i

        'now it has assigned random values...

    For i = 6 To lastRow
        For j = i + 1 To lastRow
            '14 is the number column...
            If Cells(j, 14).Value < Cells(i, 14).Value Then

                'change the string, which is the Emp column...
                tempString = Cells(i, 13).Value
                Cells(i, 13).Value = Cells(j, 13).Value
                Cells(j, 13).Value = tempString

                tempInteger = Cells(i, 14).Value
                Cells(i, 14).Value = Cells(j, 14).Value
                Cells(j, 14).Value = tempInteger
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Worksheets("Test").Range("N:N").EntireColumn.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Here is the macro for turning that list into an array:

```
Sub EmpArray()
' This stores the column of Emps as an array

    Dim Storage() As String ' initial storage array to take values
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lrow As Long

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row ' The amount of stuff in the column

    ReDim Storage(1 To lrow - 5)

    For i = lrow To 6 Step -1
        If (Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 13).Value)) Then ' checks to make sure the value isn't empty
            j = j + 1
            Storage(j) = Cells(i, 13).Value
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve Storage(1 To j)

    For j = LBound(Storage) To UBound(Storage)  ' loop through the previous array
        MsgBox (Storage(j))
    Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: This is solvable directly on a worksheet without VBA. Give it a go!

Comment: I think the idea is for my boss to have a "push-button" sort where the list of employees he entered just get automatically assigned. At least the instructions were "if you could do that, you would save us hours every week", so here I am. Could I push the button to call my two macros and then have it call the ActiveSheet.WorksheetFunction()?

Comment: I'd still deliver it on a Ctrl+Alt+F9 if I could. Macros are a pain as they are difficult to version control and maintain. But they do occasionally have their uses.

Comment: What is the amount of tasks do you have? What about employees? Do you have a separate enumerated table with tasks? Do you need all tasks to be assigned? Or only part of them? Are tasks equaly difficult? Should you consider weekly workload per each employee? Can you assign same task to two different employees?

Comment: @AntiDrondert I'm not in a position to make If_Then decisions, that is on management. The number of tasks can change, so I will use the lrow count method as outlined in my macros. # of employees is already counted in the macro. All tasks obviously need to be assigned. I just need the list to automatically sort. I'll attach the table that I am working with, which should answer most of your questions.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you've already assigned tasks by now? Are numbers after each `PA` is a number of task? And you only need to put these `PA`s to corresponding cells in `Task` table (column `Assignee`)?

Comment: No, and although I really appreciate you taking the time to read through my inquiry, I think you're completely missing my point. I would be glad to take this to chat if you think that would be easier.

It is fairly simple. There is a list of employees - PA (company name) and their number is just a way of hiding their name. The employee column is the employee column. I have macros written that randomize that column & turn it into an array. I am now failing with finding a way to assign, i.e. loop through and place each employee next to a task in the Assignee column.

Comment: Obviously, as mentioned in my initial post, each employee needs to be assigned once, and can be assigned no more than two times. I know how to loop THROUGH an array, but I can't logically think of a way to do what I need.

Comment: @bm0r3son It will be easier to communicate in chat, I might interpret task a little differently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164761/discussion-between-bm0r3son-and-antidrondert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your entire program here. It's tested and works. The only problem is that your screenshot didn't show the row and column headers, so I had to assume that **Task** was column B, row 1.

Here is your main Subroutine. This is the program that you will assign your button to. This will automatically check to see if your `employeeList` is uninitialized (basically empty) and rebuild it using the function `buildOneDimArr`.

```
Sub assignEmployeeTasks()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim employeeList() As Variant

    With ws
        For i = 2 To lastRow(ws, 2)
            If (Not employeeList) = -1 Then
                'rebuild employeelist / array uninitialized
                employeeList = buildOneDimArr(ws, "F", 2, lastRow(ws, "F"))
            End If
            .Cells(i, 4) = randomEmployee(employeeList)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

These are the "support" functions that allow your program to do it's job:

```
Function randomEmployee(ByRef employeeList As Variant) As String

    'Random # that will determine the employee chosen
    Dim Lotto As Long
    Lotto = randomNumber(LBound(employeeList), UBound(employeeList))
    randomEmployee = employeeList(Lotto)

    'Remove the employee from the original array before returning it to the sub
    Dim retArr() As Variant, i&, x&, numRem&
    numRem = UBound(employeeList) - 1
    If numRem = -1 Then     'array is empty
        Erase employeeList
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReDim retArr(numRem)
    For i = 0 To UBound(employeeList)
        If i <> Lotto Then
            retArr(x) = employeeList(i)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Erase employeeList
    employeeList = retArr

End Function

' This will take your column of employees and place them in a 1-D array
Function buildOneDimArr(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal Col As Variant, _
        ByVal rowStart As Long, ByVal rowEnd As Long) As Variant()

    Dim numElements As Long, i As Long, x As Long, retArr()
    numElements = rowEnd - rowStart
    ReDim retArr(numElements)

    For i = rowStart To rowEnd
        retArr(x) = ws.Cells(i, Col)
        x = x + 1
    Next i

    buildOneDimArr = retArr

End Function

' This outputs a random number so you can randomly assign your employee
Function randomNumber(ByVal lngMin&, ByVal lngMax&) As Long
    'Courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/22628599/5781745
    Randomize
    randomNumber = Int((lngMax - lngMin + 1) * Rnd + lngMin)
End Function

' This gets the last row of any column you specify in the arguments
Function lastRow(ws As Worksheet, Col As Variant) As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

You are going to want to place all of these into a standard module.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure you are missing the function randomEmployee somewhere

Comment: I would also add at least one randomize function in there so rnd is more random

Comment: @Mono See my answer on OP's last post. I did a test on `randomNumber` and it is pretty reliable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48364841/5781745

Comment: Your test only shows that it has a normal distribution which is expected. The randomize function makes sure that the actual outcome really is different. Else you always get the exact same "random" numbers with a normal distribution of course. For reference https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/randomize.php

Comment: You can test it quite easily. Create a small function which fills 100 Rows with rnd numbers from 0 to 10 in your sheet and run it. Save it and close the book. Reopen it and run it again this time one column next to it.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs , thank you so much for taking the time to share this with me. It works beautifully. Thank you very much! I am examining the code now to learn from it...

Comment: @bm0r3son the best part is it’s dynamic. You can use this for 5 employees with 100 tasks or 100 employees with 5 tasks. It fairly assigns employees randomly (thanks mono for the randomization comment).

Comment: I noticed that. When I was changing the main method around to work on the larger set of data, I just needed to change around the one parent macro. Thank you so much for the comments and helping me better understand passing datasheet objects back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution for you which might help you to develop further also in general understanding of programming.

With my solution you dont need to shuffle your employees beforehand and you will use some stuff you might have not used before.
First of all I created a new Class Module called Employee which looks like this:

```
Private p_name As String
Private p_task As String

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = p_name
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal value As String)
p_name = value
End Property

Public Property Get Task() As String
    Task = p_task
End Property

Public Property Let Task(ByVal value As String)
p_task = value
End Property
```

This is only a small class to hold an employeename and a task.
In a normal Module I added a method called ShuffleTasks with 2 collections as parameters. A Collection is a slightly more comfortable and therefor slightly heavier and slower version of an array.

```
Private Sub ShuffleTasks(t As Collection, emp As Collection)
Dim i As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim employ As employee
count = emp.count
Dim remIndex  As Integer
For i = 1 To count
'randomize
Randomize
'get a random index from tasks by its count
remIndex = Int((t.count) * Rnd + 1)
'add the task to the employee list
emp.Item(i).Task = t.Item(remIndex)
'remove the task so it wont be assigned again
t.Remove (remIndex)
Next
End Sub
```

The first parameter is a collection of the tasks(which is just a string with the name), the second the collection of the employees. The second one will also the one being used as the result.
Then I iterate through all employees and generate a random integer between 1 and the count of the tasks. I'll add the task to the current employee in the collection and REMOVE it from the tasklist. In the next iteration the numbers of tasks will be -1 and again randomized chosen from the amount of items in the collection.

Then I modified your EmpArray Method to fill some data from a sheet and call the ShuffleTasks method

```
Sub EmpArray()
' This stores the column of Emps as an Collection

    Dim sEmployees As New Collection, sTasks As New Collection ' initial storage array to take values
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim s As Variant
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim emp As employee
    lrow = Cells(Rows.count, "M").End(xlUp).Row ' The amount of stuff in the column

    For i = lrow To 6 Step -1
        If (Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 13).value)) Then ' checks to make sure the value isn't empty
            j = j + 1
            'Storage(j) = Cells(i, 13).Value
            Set emp = New employee
            emp.Name = Cells(i, 13).value
            sEmployees.Add emp
        End If
    Next i
' This stores the column of Tasks as an Collection
' I assume it is column 9
lrow = Cells(Rows.count, "I").End(xlUp).Row ' The amount of stuff in the column
    For i = lrow To 6 Step -1
        If (Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 9).value)) Then ' checks to make sure the value isn't empty
            j = j + 1
            sTasks.Add Cells(i, 9).value

        End If
    Next i
ShuffleTasks sTasks, sEmployees
For Each emp In sEmployees
    Debug.Print (emp.Name & ": " & emp.Task)
Next

End Sub
```

As you can see the modifications on the Collection will show you each time a new employee name and task. Keep in mind that it is ofc not true random. Also the collection of tasks will have less items after the method ShuffleTasks. I just wanted to show you an approach which is basically working a bit with data in vba. You only load data from the sheet, then manipulate that in pure vba objects. The results can also be written back to the sheet, I just print them to Debug Window in your vba editor.

Hope this helps. It is for sure a quick and dirty solution and I also didnt cover all aspects of Collections and also Parameters and ByVal vs ByRef etc. But maybe this will inspire you a bit ;)

Comment: thank you so much for this. It is definitely reminiscent of building a class in Java and doing things that way. Frankly, reading this just made me aware of how poor and lacking I have been with truly employing data structures and programming tactics to VBA. Thank you for lighting a fire under my bum :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood it correctly:

```
Sub AssignEmpl() 
    Dim TaskTable As Range, EmpTable As Range 
    Dim lRowT As Long, lRowE As Long, iCell As Range 
    lRowT = Worksheets("Test").Range("I" & Worksheets("Test").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
    lRowE = Worksheets("Test").Range("M" & Worksheets("Test").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
    ' Don't know what are actual ranges, modify 
    Set TaskTable = Worksheets("Test").Range("I6:K" & lRowT) 
    Set EmpTable = Worksheets("Test").Range("M6:M" & lRowE) 
    ' Starting loop 
    Do 
        ' Populate column with random nubmers between 1 and number of employees 
        ' 5 is a number of employees (essentialy lRowE - 5 or something like that) 
        TaskTable.Columns(3).Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(1," & lRowE - 5 & ")" 
        ' Remove formula (so it doesn't recalculate) 
        TaskTable.Columns(3).Value = TaskTable.Columns(3).Value 
        ' Check if any number appears more than 2 times 
    Loop While Evaluate("AND(MAX(COUNTIF(" & TaskTable.Columns(3).Address & "," & TaskTable.Columns(3).Address & "))>2)") 
    '    Put these employee in there
    For Each iCell In TaskTable.Columns(3).Cells 
        iCell.Value = EmpTable.Cells(iCell.Value, 1) 
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for all of your help today. I really appreciated your patience.

Comment: @bm0r3son No problem :)