# Is there a way evenly assign employees to a large task list while accounting for some criteria conditions?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula

I have a dynamic population of tasks that I receive monthly, I want to assign these tasks to 6 groups for them to assess in an evenly distributed fashion. Each task has a ranking/priority, so if a group receives the number 1 task, I don't want to also give that same group the top 100 priorities. I want to apply a snaking/zigzag distribution.

This led me down a path to using the formula `=MIN(MOD(ROW()-2,12),MOD(-ROW()+1,12))`. I get the distribution I'm looking for, although at this stage I don't know how to account for any criteria that I need to add into my logic.

[image]

In the above image I am trying to take the groups in `column F` and apply them to `Column D`. `Column E` shows the example of the `=MOD()` formula and I could just use a lookup to replace the Mod values of 0-5 with my groups 1-6.

Where I hit a roadblock is in row 21, which is where I want to account for some criteria, or exceptions. I added a binary `column A` for visualization, but essentially, I want to say where column C (task location) `= Loc4` to never assign a task to `Group 4`. In the instance where I don't want a task to be assigned to Group 4 at Loc 4, I then hope to skip `Group 4` for a single assignment until it can be applied to the next possible ranked task. The simple solution is to remove all these occurrences at the end, but it really skews the even distribution I'm going for.

I tried to apply solver to this assignment, looking for the lowest std deviation, but I have too many data points.

This has led me to another post using some vba logic, which I really like the concept, but I cannot figure out how to modify it to account for some exceptions. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687179/randomly-assign-employees-to-tasks?noredirect=1#comment84372012_48687179)

Ideally I would love to use this concept of creating a single array of my groups, applying each group to a task as long as the criteria is met in this short list of task, write the groups into the list, reset and move down to the next subset of tasks. So, each time I select the next 6 tasks, they are assigned to one of my 6 groups, which will keep the distribution that I'm hoping for.

Here is the code from the user **K.Davis** post which I was trying to apply:

```
    Sub assignEmployeeTasks()

            Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Dim employeeList() As Variant

        With ws
            For i = 2 To lastRow(ws, 2)
                If (Not employeeList) = -1 Then
                    'rebuild employeelist / array uninitialized
                    employeeList = buildOneDimArr(ws, "F", 2, lastRow(ws, "F"))
                End If
                .Cells(i, 4) = randomEmployee(employeeList)
            Next
        End With

    End Sub
```

These are the "support" functions that allow your program to do it's job:

```
Function randomEmployee(ByRef employeeList As Variant) As String

    'Random # that will determine the employee chosen
    Dim Lotto As Long
    Lotto = randomNumber(LBound(employeeList), UBound(employeeList))
    randomEmployee = employeeList(Lotto)

    'Remove the employee from the original array before returning it to the sub
    Dim retArr() As Variant, i&, x&, numRem&
    numRem = UBound(employeeList) - 1
    If numRem = -1 Then     'array is empty
        Erase employeeList
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReDim retArr(numRem)
    For i = 0 To UBound(employeeList)
        If i <> Lotto Then
            retArr(x) = employeeList(i)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Erase employeeList
    employeeList = retArr

End Function

' This will take your column of employees and place them in a 1-D array
Function buildOneDimArr(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal Col As Variant, _
        ByVal rowStart As Long, ByVal rowEnd As Long) As Variant()

    Dim numElements As Long, i As Long, x As Long, retArr()
    numElements = rowEnd - rowStart
    ReDim retArr(numElements)

    For i = rowStart To rowEnd
        retArr(x) = ws.Cells(i, Col)
        x = x + 1
    Next i

    buildOneDimArr = retArr

End Function

' This outputs a random number so you can randomly assign your employee
Function randomNumber(ByVal lngMin&, ByVal lngMax&) As Long
    'Courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/22628599/5781745
    Randomize
    randomNumber = Int((lngMax - lngMin + 1) * Rnd + lngMin)
End Function

' This gets the last row of any column you specify in the arguments
Function lastRow(ws As Worksheet, Col As Variant) As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I'm up for any path that gets closer to my desired solution, formulas or vba. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks!

Comment: You could checkout the Solver and assignment models - may be easier than vba...

Comment: Thanks! I'll take another look into the options surrounding Solver and review some assignment models. My data set has over 150K records/tasks, so I assumed I had too many variables, but maybe I can break the data into subsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program works on a block of tasks at a time where the block size is a multiple of the group count. I have SIZE=2 to give a block size of 12 as this gives more opportunity to resolve conflicts than 6 would. It works by initially assigning the tasks to a zigzap pattern and then validates this against the rules you define. These are in the module validLocn(). If the validation is OK the process moves down the sheet to the next block. If the validation fails the plan is shuffled by swapping 2 element randomly chosen and validation retried. This continues up the maximum number set by MAXTRY. If still not resolved the user can chose to retry again, ignore and move on or abort the process. I have tested it with 150,000 records and it took less than a minute, but my test data may not represent your real data. The results in a pivot table on cols B,C,D show even distribution and no tasks for Grp4 at Locn4.

```
Count of Task                               
Row     Loc1    Loc2    Loc3    Loc4    Loc5    Loc6    Gand Total
Gp1     4013    3975    3926    5082    3986    4018    25000
Gp2     4021    3992    4077    4928    3975    4007    25000
Gp3     3976    3952    4027    5023    4049    3973    25000
Gp4     5050    4915    4936            5035    5064    25000
Gp5     4072    3996    4034    4890    3969    4039    25000
Gp6     3964    4087    3986    5018    3996    3949    25000                               
Grand  25096    24917   24986   24941   25010   25050   150000
```

Hope that helps.

```
Option Explicit
Sub assignEmployeeTasks()


    Dim ws As Worksheet, t0 As Single, t1 As Single
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    t0 = Timer

    Const COL_GROUP = "F"
    Const COL_LOCN = "C"
    Const SIZE As Integer = 2 ' plan size =  2 * group count

    Const MAXTRY = 50 ' no of tries to validate

    Dim bOK As Boolean
    Dim grp As Variant, iBlockStart As Long, i As Integer, r As Integer, step As Integer

     'initialize grps and location
    Dim countGrp As Integer, lastLocn As Long
    lastLocn = ws.Range(COL_LOCN & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    countGrp = ws.Range(COL_GROUP & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    grp = ws.Range(COL_GROUP & "2").Resize(countGrp, 1).Value
    Dim plan() As String
    ReDim plan(countGrp * SIZE, 2)

    Dim itry As Integer, res
    iBlockStart = 1

    Do While iBlockStart < lastLocn

        ' initialize plan
        Call zigzag(plan, grp)
        For i = 1 To UBound(plan)
            plan(i, 1) = ws.Range("C" & iBlockStart + i).Value
        Next

        ' save 1st attempt
        For i = 1 To UBound(plan)
            ws.Range("D" & iBlockStart + i).Value = plan(i, 2)
        Next

        ' validate
        bOK = validLocn(plan, 0)

retry:

        ' retry to validate
        itry = 0
        While bOK = False And itry < MAXTRY
            Call shuffle(plan, 1)
            bOK = validLocn(plan, itry)
            itry = itry + 1
        Wend

        ' write new plan to sheet
        For i = 1 To UBound(plan)
            ws.Range("D" & iBlockStart + i).Value = plan(i, 2)
        Next

        ' check rule again
        If itry = MAXTRY Then
            ws.Range(COL_LOCN & iBlockStart).Select
            res = MsgBox("Failed to vaidate after " & MAXTRY & " attempts", vbAbortRetryIgnore, iBlockStart)
            If res = vbRetry Then GoTo retry
            If res = vbAbort Then Exit Sub
        End If
        iBlockStart = iBlockStart + UBound(plan)
    Loop
    t1 = Timer
    MsgBox "Assigned " & lastLocn - 1 & " tasks in " & Int(t1 - t0) & " secs"

End Sub

 ' valid plan against rules
Function validLocn(plan As Variant, itry) As Boolean
    Dim sLocn As String, sGrp As String, i As Integer

    validLocn = True
    For i = 1 To UBound(plan)
        sLocn = plan(i, 1)
        sGrp = plan(i, 2)
        ' rule 1
        If sGrp = "Gp4" And sLocn = "Loc4" Then
            validLocn = False
            'Debug.Print itry, i, "Fail Rule 1", sGrp, sLocn
        Else
            'Debug.Print itry, i, "Pass Rule 1", sGrp, sLocn
        End If
    Next
End Function

' populate plan groups
Sub zigzag(plan As Variant, grp As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer, r As Integer, step As Integer
    r = 1: step = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(plan)
        plan(i, 2) = grp(r, 1)
        r = r + step
        If r > UBound(grp) Then
            r = UBound(grp)
            step = -1
        ElseIf r < 1 Then
           r = 1
           step = 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub

' shuffle plan
Sub shuffle(plan As Variant, i As Integer)
    Dim tmp As String, n As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    For n = 1 To i
       ' random choose elements to shuffle
retry:
        k = Int(1 + Rnd() * UBound(plan))
        j = Int(1 + Rnd() * UBound(plan))
        If k = j Then GoTo retry
        tmp = plan(k, 2)
        plan(k, 2) = plan(j, 2)
        plan(j, 2) = tmp
    Next
End Sub


' generate test data
Sub testdata()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 2 To 150001
        ws.Cells(i, 2) = i - 1
        ws.Cells(i, 3) = "Loc" & 1 + Int(Rnd() * 6)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the slow response. Looking forward giving this code a try over the weekend. Appreciate the input!

Comment: @intromind That's Ok, use latest revision because I have corrected a potential bug in the shuffle sub.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This works great! I can add this as a table in my database to maintain the speed of the program and keep the data input simple. I appreciate the comments as well so I can follow along, as I need to challenge myself develop solutions from scratch rather than piecing others solutions together.