# How do I make it so cells in excel randomize a range of numbers when I select a drop down item in another cell?

Tags: excel, social-gaming

I'm looking to make an easy excel sheet for beginners of a board game my friends and I are into. I'm trying to make it so that once they select a drop down menu it will correspond to randomizing a range of whole numbers in certain cells. I tried googling online and nothing I found was helpful. I'm truly a beginner and a friend pointed me to this forum, I'm just trying to start a D&D club in the new town I moved into to make some friends outside of work. Any help is much appreciated everybody. I can attach screenshots of the sheet I have if that would help anybody visualize it.

Comment: One way to do it is to run a macro when that particular cell (the one that contains the dropdown) change. Then use `RandBetween` function to generate a random number in a range. This would require you to understand some basic coding

Comment: [This method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22628599/5781745) will get you your random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function Randbetween():

```
=randbetween(1,30)
```

To give a random range between 1 and 30.

Note, this is a volatile function, so as long as calculation is set on automatic, any selection of other cells etc will cause the randbetween() to re-calculate...